# How can I get specific value in array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I will explain clearly

```
$array  = array("1" => array(0 =>"aa",1 =>"bb", 2 => "cc",3=>"dd"),
                "2" => array(0 =>"aa1",1 =>"bb1", 2 => "cc1",3=>"dd1"));
```

In this two dimension are

```
$array2[$a][$b];
```

I know $a value and $b is unknown

If I using `$a =1`, I want to filter `array(0 =>"aa",1 =>"bb", 2 => "cc",3=>"dd")` this array

But I need to get the second array element. Any function is available to do that?

Comment: what do you want as the result? 'b'?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense, can you try and clarify what you need to do?

Comment: @everyone, he wants to show the value of key `2` and then remove it from the array (throw-out / bring-out).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
$a = array(1=>'a', 2=>'b', 3=>'c');

//display the value with key 2:
echo $a[2];

//remove the value with key 2 (throw-out / bring-out in your language)
unset($a[2]);

//now display whole array to show that value with key 2 is gone
print_r($a);
```

This outputs:

> b

And then it outputs:

> Array ( [1] => a [3] => c )

Answer (score 0):

make new array you want to sperate specific elements that key

```
$newarr = array(2,5,8);
foreach($arr1 as v1){
foreach($arr2 as $k => $v2 ){
if (in_array($k,$newarr))
{
// process ... 
}
}
}
```